# Doxygen custom ALIAS

Tags: doxygen

I wanted to create a custom ALIAS `@modified` which includes `@date` and `@author`and gives me the HTML output:

**Modified:**
17.05.2013 TEST
25.12.0033 jESUS Christos

this resulted in:

`ALIASES            += modified{1}{2}="\par Modified: @date\1 @author\2 \n"`

to test it, I wrote the following comment in my c-File

`*  @modified   17.05.2013 TEST`

`*  @modified   25.12.0033 jESUS Christos`

but the corresponding HTML output wasn't quite what I expected:

17.05.2013 TEST 25.12.0033 jESUS Christos

So I'm missing the **Modified:** and linebreaks at the end of a @modified tag.
Any suggestion why and how it can be fixed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your syntax is a bit off the mark.

Put this in your `Doxyfile`.

```
ALIASES += mod="\b Modified:\n"
ALIASES += moditem{2}="\par @date\1 @author\2 \n"
```

and this in your code.

```
* @mod
* @moditem{ 17.05.2013, TEST }
* @moditem{ 25.12.0033, jESUS Christos }
```

You might also want to define an `@endmod` alias to "close" the above comment block, but it isn't necessary.